# Data didnt bind to the grid view in asp .net

Tags: .net, stored-procedures

This is the code

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
if (txtFdate.Text == "")
{
Response.Write("alert('Please select From date...')"); return;
}
if (txtTdate.Text == "")
{
Response.Write("alert('Please select To date...')"); return;
}

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("CR_GET_REQUESTEDCRBYDATE", connString);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fdate", txtFdate.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tdate", txtTdate.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", dpBranch1.SelectedValue.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", dpReason1.SelectedValue.ToString());

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

            try
            {
                connString.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            grdREQCR.DataSource = dt;
            grdREQCR.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connString.Close();
        }
    }
```

this is stored procedure

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CR_GET_REQUESTEDCRBYDATE]

```
@fdate  date,
@tdate  date,
@Branch varchar(50),
@Reason varchar(50)
```

AS
BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT d.ID, d.FacNo 'Facility no', d.customer_name 'Customer name', d.vehicle_no 'Vehicle No', 
d.running_date 'Running Date', d.Branch, d.facility_type 'Facility Type', f.DESCR 'Facility Status', 
r.DESCR 'Reason', b.Name 'Send Branch', d.Username 'Request By'
FROM CR_SAVE_FACILITY_DETAILS d 
inner join CR_FACILITY_STATUS f on f.CODE = d.Facility_Status
inner join CR_REASON r on r.CODE = d.Reason
inner join Branch b on b.CODE = d.To_branch
where Branch=@Branch AND Reason=@Reason AND DATE>=@fdate AND DATE<=@tdate
```

END

i want to bind data to grid view from stored procedure